# Tensorflow Seq2Seq ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

This code intended as a Seq2Seq model...

```
# imports
from utils import get_sorted_buckets

import logging
from six.moves import xrange

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# classes
class Seq2Seq:
    def __init__(self,
                 input_vocab_size,
                 output_vocab_size,
                 buckets,
                 layer_size=256,
                 n_layers=3,
                 max_gradient_norm=5.0,
                 batch_size=64,
                 learning_rate=0.5,
                 learning_rate_decay_factor=0.99,
                 rnn_cell=tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell,
                 n_samples=512,
                 forward_only=False):
        logging.info('initializing Seq2Seq model')
        buckets = get_sorted_buckets(buckets)

        self.input_vocab_size = input_vocab_size
        self.output_vocab_size = output_vocab_size
        self.buckets = buckets
        self.layer_size = layer_size
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.max_gradient_norm = max_gradient_norm
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.learning_rate_decay_factor = learning_rate_decay_factor
        self.rnn_cell = rnn_cell
        self.n_samples = n_samples
        self.forward_only = forward_only

        self.learning_rate = tf.Variable(float(self.learning_rate),
                                         trainable=False)
        self.learning_rate_decay_operation = self.learning_rate.assign(
                        self.learning_rate * self.learning_rate_decay_factor)
        self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

        self.encoder_inputs = [self._get_val_placeholder('encoder', i)
                               for i in xrange(buckets[-1][0])]

        self.decoder_inputs = [self._get_val_placeholder('decoder', i)
                               for i in xrange(buckets[-1][1] + 1)]
        self.target_weights = [self._get_val_placeholder('weight', i,
                                                         dtype=tf.float32)
                               for i in xrange(buckets[-1][1] + 1)]

        logging.debug('getting model')
        self.outputs, self.losses = self._get_model_with_buckets()

        self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

        if not forward_only:
            logging.debug('setting gradient norms and updates')
            out = self._get_gradient_norms_and_updates()
            self.gradient_norms, self.updates = out

    def _get_softmax_loss_func_and_output_proj(self):
        logging.debug('function: _get_softmax_loss_func_and_output_proj')
        use_sampled_softmax = self.n_samples > 0 and \
                              self.n_samples < self.output_vocab_size
        if use_sampled_softmax:
            w = tf.get_variable('proj_w',
                                [self.layer_size, self.output_vocab_size],
                                dtype=tf.int32)
            w_t = tf.transpose(w)
            b = tf.get_variable('proj_b',
                                [self.output_vocab_size],
                                dtype=tf.int32)

            def get_sampled_loss(inputs, labels):
                labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])

                print(w_t)
                print(b)
                print(labels)
                print(inputs)

                return tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                    weights=w_t, biases=b, labels=labels, inputs=inputs,
                    num_sampled=self.n_samples,
                    num_classes=self.output_vocab_size)

            softmax_loss_function = get_sampled_loss
            output_projection = (w, b)
        else:
            softmax_loss_function = None
            output_projection = None

        return softmax_loss_function, output_projection

    def _get_cell(self):
        logging.debug('function: _get_cell')
        single_cell = self.rnn_cell(self.layer_size)
        # single_cell = self.rnn_cell

        if self.n_layers > 1:
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([single_cell] * self.n_layers)
        else:
            cell = single_cell

        return cell

    def _get_val_placeholder(self, name, idx, dtype=tf.int32):
        return tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=[None], name='{}_{}'.format(name,
                                                                       idx))

    def _get_model_with_buckets(self):
        targets = [self.decoder_inputs[i + 1]
                   for i in xrange(len(self.decoder_inputs) - 1)]

        out = self._get_softmax_loss_func_and_output_proj()
        softmax_loss_function, output_projection = out

        cell = self._get_cell()

        def seq2seq_func(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, do_decode):
            print('seq2seq: {} {} {}'.format(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, do_decode))
            return tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq(
              encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, cell,
              num_encoder_symbols=self.input_vocab_size,
              num_decoder_symbols=self.output_vocab_size,
              embedding_size=self.layer_size,
              output_projection=output_projection,
              feed_previous=do_decode)

        logging.debug('getting model with buckets')
        outputs, losses = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.model_with_buckets(
           self.encoder_inputs, self.decoder_inputs, targets,
           self.target_weights, self.buckets,
           lambda x, y: seq2seq_func(x, y, self.forward_only),
           softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)

        logging.debug('forward only')
        if self.forward_only:
            if output_projection is not None:
                for i in xrange(len(self.buckets)):
                    w = output_projection[0]
                    b = output_projection[1]
                    new_bucket_outputs = [tf.matmul(output, w) + b
                                          for output in outputs[i]]

                    self.outputs[i] = new_bucket_outputs

        return outputs, losses

    def _get_gradient_norms_and_updates(self):
        params = tf.trainable_variables()

        gradient_norms = []
        updates = []

        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
        for i in xrange(len(self.buckets)):
            gradients = tf.gradients(self.losses[i], params)
            clipped_gradients, norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(
                gradients, self.max_gradient_norm)
            gradient_norms.append(norm)
            updates.append(optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(clipped_gradients, params), global_step=self.global_step))

        return gradient_norms, updates

    def step(self, session, encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, target_weights,
             bucket_id, forward_only):
        encoder_size, decoder_size = self.buckets[bucket_id]
        if len(encoder_inputs) != encoder_size:
            raise ValueError('Encoder length must be equal to one in bucket.')
        elif len(decoder_inputs) != decoder_size:
            raise ValueError('Decoder length must be equal to one in bucket.')
        elif len(target_weights) != decoder_size:
            raise ValueError('Weights length must be equal to one in bucket.')

        input_feed = {}
        for i in xrange(encoder_size):
            input_feed[self.encoder_inputs[i].name] = encoder_inputs[i]
        for i in xrange(decoder_size):
            input_feed[self.decoder_inputs[i].name] = decoder_inputs[i]
            input_feed[self.target_weights[i].name] = target_weights[i]

        last_target = self.decoder_inputs[decoder_size].name
        input_feed[last_target] = np.zeros([self.batch_size], dtype=np.int32)

        if forward_only:
            output_feed = [self.losses[bucket_id]]

            for i in xrange(decoder_size):
                output_feed.append(self.outputs[bucket_id][i])
        else:
            output_feed = [self.updates[bucket_id],
                           self.gradient_norms[bucket_id],
                           self.losses[bucket_id]]

        outputs = session.run(output_feed, input_feed)

        if not forward_only:
            return outputs[1], outputs[2], None
        else:
            return None, outputs[0], outputs[1:]
```

Generates this error...

```
INFO:root:initializing Seq2Seq model
DEBUG:root:getting model
DEBUG:root:function: _get_softmax_loss_func_and_output_proj
DEBUG:root:function: _get_cell
DEBUG:root:getting model with buckets
seq2seq: [<tf.Tensor 'encoder_0:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_7:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_10:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_11:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_14:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_15:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_16:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_17:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_18:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'encoder_19:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>] [<tf.Tensor 'decoder_0:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_7:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoder_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>] False
Tensor("transpose:0", shape=(20000, 256), dtype=int32)
Tensor("proj_b/read:0", shape=(20000,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("model_with_buckets/sequence_loss/sequence_loss_by_example/Reshape:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("decoder_1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 670, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    status)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'model_with_buckets/sequence_loss/sequence_loss_by_example/sampled_softmax_loss/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [?,256].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 82, in main
    model = get_model()
  File "train.py", line 76, in get_model
    get_rnn_cell(), FLAGS.n_samples, FLAGS.forward_only)
  File "/Users/edholm/Desktop/Seq2Seq/model.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.outputs, self.losses = self._get_model_with_buckets()
  File "/Users/edholm/Desktop/Seq2Seq/model.py", line 141, in _get_model_with_buckets
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 1195, in model_with_buckets
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 1110, in sequence_loss
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 1067, in sequence_loss_by_example
    crossent = softmax_loss_function(target, logit)
  File "/Users/edholm/Desktop/Seq2Seq/model.py", line 91, in get_sampled_loss
    num_classes=self.output_vocab_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 1191, in sampled_softmax_loss
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 995, in _compute_sampled_logits
    inputs, sampled_w, transpose_b=True) + sampled_b
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1855, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1454, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2397, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1757, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1707, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'model_with_buckets/sequence_loss/sequence_loss_by_example/sampled_softmax_loss/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [?,256].
```

The error probably has to do with the sampled softmax loss, I've had a lot of errors before that has to do with new update of Tensorflow, new syntax order of arguments and so on. There's maybe more errors in the code but I'll have to solve this one before encountering more.

Two days have passed and I don't still know what to do. What changes in the code should I make to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

In a new Tensorflow update they reversed the order of arguments in `sampled_softmax_loss`.

Don't use this.

```
def get_sampled_loss(inputs, labels):
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])

    return tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                    weights=w_t, biases=b, labels=labels, inputs=inputs,
                    num_sampled=self.n_samples,
                    num_classes=self.output_vocab_size)
```

Instead use this.

```
def get_sampled_loss(labels, inputs):
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])

    return tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                    weights=w_t, biases=b, labels=labels, inputs=inputs,
                    num_sampled=self.n_samples,
                    num_classes=self.output_vocab_size)
```

The difference between the two snippets is instead of having the arguments in this order: `get_sampled_loss(inputs, labels)`.

Use this order: `get_sampled_loss(labels, inputs)`